# Should I free a temp pointer used to traverse a linked list?

Tags: c, pointers, free, doubly-linked-list

If I have something like:

```
function(DLL *dll) {
    DLL_Node *temp = dll->head

    // do stuff with temp like traverse list with temp=temp->next

    // say when done, temp = dll->tail, should I free(temp) or leave it alone?
}
```

I'm still not very experienced with pointers, it seems like I created an extra pointer, but it just points to a position in the list, so I shouldn't free it and it will get cleared when function ends?

By the way I defined `DLL` and `DLL_Node` like this:

```
typedef struct dll_node {
    int data;
    struct dll_node *prev;
    struct dll_node *next;
} DLL_Node;

typedef struct DLL_ {
    int count;
    DLL_Node *head;
    DLL_Node *tail;
} DLL;
```

I saw a recommendation for the program valgrind for testing for memory leaks and it says definitely lost and indirectly lost are both 0 bytes, but possibly lost is 2,064 bytes. Not sure what that means exactly or if it's relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `free` does not free a pointer, it frees whatever the pointer points to. Simply declaring and using a pointer does not call for freeing, so you do not need to free a pointer that has been used to traverse a list.

General rule is that you need to call `free` on everything that has been returned to you by `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc`. There needs to be only one call of `free` on each allocated block. Freeing the same block twice results in *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Thanks that's what I was thinking, but I wasn't quite sure. Any idea if the possibly lost bytes shown by valgrind is something to worry about?

Comment: @Jake Possibly lost means that your program no longer holds a pointer to some of the allocated blocks, but there are pointers into the middle of it. If you use some pointer arithmetics with the blocks you allocate, valgrind would produce "possibly lost" warnings.

Answer (score 1):

To just add to what @dasblinkenlight said, you need not delete/remove it explicitly. Since *temp is inside the function's scope, it will be gone once the function returns.

Since you are concerned about the unused memory, just a reminder - pointer takes 4 bytes on a 32bit machine and 8 bytes on a 64 bit machine and, not the sizeof(DLL_Node) as you might be thinking.